# How to install Grails Plugin in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, grails, grails-plugin

Im using windows and eclipse Luna. I wanted to install plugins in my grails. I didnt see where is the grails command.

Answer (score 1):

Grails 3 is not supported in Eclipse. Use Intellij U edition. 
For grails 2 use GGTS.

Answer (score 1):

In Grails2, plugins are added in **BuildConfig.groovy** which resides in 
**grails-app\conf** .

In Grails3, plugins are added in **build.gradle** file.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project -> Grails Tools -> Grails Command Wizard / Open up Grails command prompt. Depends on what commands you want :P